# JQuery, selecting children of visible div

Tags: javascript, jquery

MY HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="paj_container" class="container">
    <div class="three_paj_els">

    <div id="1" class="a_paj_element">
        <input type="hidden" class="listed_hidden_img" value="http://google.com/whatever.png" />
    </div>                               

    <div id="2" class="a_paj_element">
        <input type="hidden" class="listed_hidden_img" value="http://google.com/whatever2.png" />
    </div>  

    <div id="3" class="a_paj_element">
        <input type="hidden" class="listed_hidden_img" value="http://google.com/whatever3.png" />
    </div>                       
    </div>
</div>
```

To spare you flipping through more code, pretend each of the .a_paj_element divs is a separate page in my JQuery pagination.

To decrease page load time my plan is to shove the images on the pagination into those hidden input types' values. When the page is visible, JQuery will grab those values and use the replace with function to replace them with  tags so the images load as you flip through the pagination pages instead of all at once. Here's what I've been trying to do to achieve this:

```
var currentPage = $('.three_paj_els:visible');
currentPage.children('.listed_hidden_img').each(function() {
    var the_image_SRC = $(this).val();
    $('.listed_hidden_img').replaceWith('<img src="'+the_image_SRC+'" />');
});
```

Basically I'm trying to get the .listed_hidden_imgs replaced only in the current visible .three_paj_els

I've done this with before with lightboxes/modals to decrease load time on pages with high resolution pictures it works well on that so I figured that this would work in this application too.

Thanks a bunch for reading this far and thanks in advance to anyone who can help correct my code.

-Mike

Comment: There's an error here: var the_image_SRC = (this).val(); ...there should be a dollar sign in front of (this) => $(this).

Comment: I was trying to get the value of listed_hidden_img, if that's invalid should I try this instead $(this).attr('value');?

Comment: OHH a dollar sign, sorry i didn't see that part of your comment

Comment: Ok i added the dollar sign, still can't get it to work :(

Comment: yep, but where is the three_paj_els element in your code ?

Comment: Opps sorry i never included that in this example, i'll edit my post to include that now, sorry.

Comment: Ok i added that in, it contains 3 .a_paj_elements and represents 1 page in my pagination.

Comment: Try $(this).replaceWith instead

Comment: darn, no. i threw it into a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Utr6v/37/

Answer (score 1):

var the_image_SRC = $(this).attr('src');

Comment: Hmm it didn't work, I threw it into a fiddle if you would like to play around with it  http://jsfiddle.net/Utr6v/37

Comment: You are replacing the image by itself ?

Comment: Yeah it's taking the hidden input value and sticking it into a new img tag and relacing the hidden input with the image tag.

Comment: Yea ok i see now, i agree with you on $(this).attr('value');

Comment: but then you should just replace the src attr like $('.listed_hidden_img').attr('src', the_image_SEC);

Comment: this works, but works on all, just have to refine this to only work on the visible div $('.listed_hidden_img').replaceWith(function(){
  var the_image_SRC = $(this).val();
    return '<img src="'+the_image_SRC+'" style="width:50px; height:50px;" />';
});